# Creating a spider web chart in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, frontend

My project is using ionic 2 on the front-end, and I have a special design to code, and am not sure how to proceed it.

This is the design

[image]

If someone has an idea on how I can manage to do that, knowing that all the points can be modified and they have to be linked with a line as it is in the picture above.

Comment: idk if this would be overkill or not for your situation, but you could implement d3.js into your ionic app. Something like this would work nicely since the points will need to be dynamic. http://vizuly.io/product/corona/?demo=d3js Otherwords you could just make it an svg on canvas with modifiable points because you could still click on and use those points as anchors within an SVG. would be easier route.

Comment: This is known as a spider web or radar chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different possibilities, can do by yourself with SVG but the easiest is to use external librairies.

The best is to use d3js with custom styling :
http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/21746a9668ffdf6d8242

Or chart js which is maybe easiest and lighter than D3Js : 
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html